# Programming cable doesn't recognise Quansheng UV-5R Plus

Tags: radio-programming, uv-5r, chirp

I am trying to program my Quansheng UV-5R Plus with a Baofeng cable. The cable works on my Baofeng, so I know it is OK. I'm told on the website to treat the UV-5R Plus just like a UV-5R but what I get when I connect my radio, using Chirp, is "Error communicating with radio". "Header short read".

I am holding the programming cable in tightly, as suggested in the answer to another similar question on this site, so I am pretty confident that is OK.

Comment: I am getting the same problem with a Quansheng UV-K5 after it has had the usual firmware update. It Downloaded OK but when came to upload a new set of channels I get the same "Error communicating with radio". "Header short read".

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered the same issue with a Quansheng UV-K5(8), nomatter which software I tried to flash it OR which firmware I tried to flash it with I kept getting errors concerning it not reading the radio yet the COM port was definitley paired & nothing else using it?

Turns out you have to push REALLY REALLY hard until there is an auduble click!, once heard it should be firmly seated and flash without any problems

Mine now covers 18Mhz (not sure if it goes lower yet as it required charging immediately after the process) to 1300Mhz
I will have a play with it once charged and see exactly what the situation is